# RestClient ExecuteTaskAsync and Execute methods: confusion with "where T : new()"

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, deserialization, restsharp

So I'm writing a client SDK of a web API in C# and I am using RestClient for that purpose. I want to offer both synchronous and asynchronous methods to interact with the different endpoints.

RestClient does offer both synchronous/asynchronous methods to execute a request and use generic type parameters, but I am confused as to **why the synchronous one requires the type to offer a parameterless constructor but the asynchronous one does not:**

```
public virtual IRestResponse<T> Execute<T>(IRestRequest request, Method httpMethod) where T : new();
public virtual Task<IRestResponse<T>> ExecuteTaskAsync<T>(IRestRequest request);
```

Thank you for any insight

Comment: Maybe it's enforced further up the call stack? Try giving it a class with no parameterless constructor and see what happens.

Comment: Yes I tried doing that (using a string) and it worked even though it does not have a parameterless constructor so I must be missing something